# Python: Using Tensordot for tensor x matrix multiplication

Tags: python, numpy

Hi im tying to multiply a tensor with a matrix in the following fashion:

dimensions

W: `a x b x c`

V: `a x c`

I want Z such that

```
Z[i]=dot(W[i],V[i])
```

Z is then of dimension `a x ( (b x c) . (c x 1))`, so `(a x b)`

Ive tried `numpy.tensordot` to do this but havent been able to. Can it do what I want? If not how can I do this WITHOUT loops.

Basically the equivalent of

```
def f(W,V):    
    Z=[]    
    for i in range(len(W)):    
        Z.append(dot(W[i],V[i]))    
    return Z
```

Thanks

edit: Specifically is this achievable with tensordot?

Comment: a code snippet with your actual data and expected output may help you to receive prompt answer(s). Thanks

Comment: No matter how hard I try, I keep reading it was "tens or dot" and not "tensor dot"

Comment: @Eric - Merging this account with your registered account would enable you to edit your question directly. If you'd like for us to do this, please flag this question for moderator attention after writing "Please merge with [target account]" in the profile of the unregistered one.

Answer (score 5):

#### [`np.einsum("abc,ac -> ab", w, v)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html#numpy-einsum):

```
import numpy as np

def z_loop(w,v): # define it to check that `einsum()` gives necessary result
    z = np.empty(w.shape[:-1], dtype=w.dtype)
    for i in range(z.shape[0]):
        z[i,:] = np.dot(w[i,:], v[i,:])
    return z

w = np.random.uniform(size=(3,4,5))
v = np.random.uniform(size=w.shape[::2])
assert np.allclose(z_loop(w, v), np.einsum('abc,ac -> ab', w, v))
```

There might be simpler variants (via `dot()`, `.reshape()`) but `einsum()` is the most obvious for the task description.

```
def z_dot(w, v):
    z = np.dot(w, v[:,...,np.newaxis])
    z = z.reshape(z.shape[:-1])
    return np.diagonal(z, axis2=-1).T

assert np.allclose(z_dot(w, v), np.einsum('abc,ac -> ab', w, v))
```

Comment: Note that `einsum` is a new addition, and at the momeny only included in the development version of Numpy.

Comment: @pv: Correct. I should have mentioned it.

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
import numpy as np

a,b,c=3,5,6

r=np.random.random
W = r((a,b,c))
V = r((a,c))

Z = np.sum(W*V[:,np.newaxis,:],axis=2)
```

Doesn't use loops or newer features and should be reasonably fast. Comparing with "z_loop" from J.F. Sebastian's post:

```
print np.sum(np.abs(Z-z_loop(W,V)))
```

gives `4.99600361081e-16`.